# How do I count all the non blank cells in a column and output it in a specific cell (openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a column in excel which has a header and than list of number between 1-5 (the header is in cell A1 and the numbers are in cells A2-A6 accordingly) i want my code to count all the cells that are not blank (start from cell A2 down) and the output will be display in cell C2, for example it should give the number 5 in cell C2.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this
There is no need to skip the header row specifically, just reduce the count by 1.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

ws['C2'] = len([x.row for x in ws['A'] if x.value is not None])-1

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```